# Защита от подделки email отправителя

Tags: php, email, защита

вконтакте, например, использует для отправки письма восстановления следующий адрес -

`VK <admin@notify.vk.com>`.. письмо отправляется с поддемена `notify.vk.com`?

при попытке подделать этот адрес письмо вообще не отправляется... скажите, почему так происходит? и как добиться того же результата на моем сайте? (что бы письма не отправлялись от левых отправителей)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставить отправителя вы можете любого, насколько мне известно защиты от этого нет. А вот будет ли оно доставлено адресату, это вопрос безопасности на почтовом сервере получателя.

Вам в помощь [SPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) и [DKIM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail)